# JavaScript: joining numbers into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

So I am trying to complete a problem and been working on it all day.
I need to be able to take an input of a number. Subtract that number all the way to zero and then join the results into an array. I would then take the array and find out if any of the numbers had a remainder of zero compared to the numbers 3 and 5. No repeats allowed. I have gotten this far but its not working.

```js
function diff(number) {

  number = number + 1;

  while (number > 0) {
    number = number - 1;
  }
};

//The top code does work for getting a number 10 to 0 by one
// I can't seem to join the numbers together into an array, hence the attempt at the bottom
// ps the last number is coming up undefined


function joining(diff) {
  x = diff.join();
  console.log(x);
};
```

Comment: You should include examples of inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Sounds like a poorly explained homework problem. Im pretty sure your teacher probably asked you NOT to use stackoverflow, mine always told me not to...

Comment: That looks like fizz buzz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way to create an array of numbers from `1` to `n` is to fill an array of length `n` and simply map every value to its index + `1`.

```js
function joinNumbersUpTo(number) {
  return new Array(number)
    .fill()
    .map((_, i) => i + 1);
}

console.log(joinNumbersUpTo(10));
```

This does the exact same thing:

```js
function joinNumbersUpTo(number) {
  return Array.from({ length: number }, (_, i) => i + 1);
}

console.log(joinNumbersUpTo(10));
```

Comment: return Array.from({ length: number }, (_, i) => i + 1); could you explain this a little more for a Noob sorry appreciate the help or the other one

Comment: It creates an array of length `number` (e.g. 10 slots if `number` is 10).  Then every slot is set to `i + 1`, where `i` is the index, or position in the array.  So the first slot at position `0` would be assigned the value `0 + 1`, or `1`.  The `_` variable represents the value at the slot, which is `undefined` or `empty` because it's never been set yet.  It could be called `value` instead of `_` but it's called underscore to signify that we don't care about it.

Comment: If you liked my answer feel free to click the green check mark at the top left of it, to award me Best Answer.